# Modeling Data using Gaussian process Regression , not getting good results

Tags: python, curve-fitting, gaussian

I am trying to model my given data using GPR and have got following results. I am unable to capture that steep change in the gradient no matter what. Can anyone please give me some pointers ?

[image]

Here is my code

```
# Convert the input to a 2D array (if necessary)
falling_part_output = np.array(falling_part_output).reshape(-1, 1)

# Define the Gaussian Process Regressor with RBF kernel
kernel = ConstantKernel() + Matern(length_scale=2, nu=1) + WhiteKernel(noise_level=0.2)
gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel)

# Fit the GPR model to the data
gpr.fit(falling_part_output, falling_part_input)


# Generate x values for plotting
x = np.linspace(min(falling_part_output), max(falling_part_output), 100).reshape(-1, 1)

# Predict the output values using the GPR model
y_pred, y_std = gpr.predict(x, return_std=True)

# Plot the data points, the predicted curve, and the uncertainty
plt.scatter(falling_part_output, falling_part_input, label='Data')
plt.plot(x, y_pred, color='red', label='GPR Prediction')
plt.fill_between(x.flatten(), y_pred.flatten() - 2 * y_std, y_pred.flatten() + 2 * y_std, color='gray', alpha=0.2, label='Uncertainty')
plt.xlabel('Tip Position')
plt.ylabel('Motor Position')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```